# How to deal with implausible answers to filter questions?

Tags: dataset, survey, data-preprocessing

I work with a questionnaire that contains a variety of filter questions. In the following I will give an example how one block of this successive questions look like.

> 1. Have you ever skipped school in your life? (Yes/No)
>
>    ```
>     If answer is "No", continue with question X on the next page  
>     If answer is "Yes":
>    ```
> 2. Have you skipped school in the last year? (Yes/No)
>
>    ```
>     If answer is "No", continue with question X on the next page
>     If answer is "Yes":
>    ```
> 3. How many times have you skipped school in the last year? (... times)

The right way to answer this bunch of questions is to respond only to the subsequent question(s) number 2 and/or 3, if one has responded with a "Yes" to the respective previous question (1 resp. 2). If one has answered "No" to one of the first two questions, he or she has to skip the following question(s) and continue with the next block in the questionnaire.

Most of the participants have dealt with this questions in the manner just described. But there are also some who fill in implausible answers. With implausible I mean responding to a question even if this was not reasonable in regard to the filter.

An example:

> 1. A respondent admitted that she/he has once before skipped school in his life ("Yes" to question 1).
> 2. Following this she/he responded that she/he has not done this in the last year ("No" to question 2).
> 3. Nevertheless, she/he **incorrectly** answered to question number 3. She/He filled in that she/he has played truant 15 times in the last year.

---

The question is now:

**How to deal with these implausible answers to filter questions?**

There seem to be three obvious strategies:

- Use all information as valid regardless of their implausibility
- Recode all implausible answers as missing
- Examine all individual cases that have implausible answer patterns in regard to the filter questions -- see if one can decide on behalf of these informations if the respective answer is really implausible or not

---

I hope that suggestions can deal with these two issues:

1. The advantages and disadvantages of the listed (or other) strategies
2. **The way a recommended strategy can be realized** (if this is not very easy, like in the case of using all information or recoding all as missing)

Comment: I just have seen that there already has been some question similar to mine (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21919/how-do-i-clean-up-inconsistent-survey-data). But I think, nevertheless, that there are some points (advantages, disadvantages of obvious strategies I mentioned) that have not answered in the related question. So I will  not delete my question already...

Comment: I agree that there may be some additional components here that argue this thread could stay open.